# Take screenshot and draw it on a Windows Form using SharpDX

Tags: c#, drawing, directx, screen-capture, sharpdx

I'm trying to capture a screenshot and show it on a Windows Form (or on a Panel) using SharpDX, but I've some trouble. I capture the screenshot using `OutputDuplication.AcquireNextFrame`, but when I try to draw the caputured frame using `WindowRenderTarget.DrawBitmap` it fail with the ***WrongResourceDomain*** exception. I added a Form and modified the code of the [ScreenCapture sample](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/Direct3D11.1/ScreenCapture/Program.cs) to illustrate my problem:

```cs
using System;
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Direct2D1;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.DXGI;

namespace MiniTri
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   Screen capture of the desktop using DXGI OutputDuplication.
    /// </summary>
    internal static class Program
    {

        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            var Form1 = new ScreenCapture.Form1();

            // # of graphics card adapter
            const int numAdapter = 0;

            // # of output device (i.e. monitor)
            const int numOutput = 0;

            // Create DXGI Factory1
            var dxgiFactory = new SharpDX.DXGI.Factory1();
            var dxgiAdapter = dxgiFactory.GetAdapter1(numAdapter);

            // Create device from Adapter
            var d3dDevice = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device(dxgiAdapter, DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport);

            // Create Direct2D1 Factory1
            var d2dFactory = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory1();

            // Create Direct2D device
            SharpDX.Direct2D1.Device d2dDevice;
            using (var dxgiDevice = d3dDevice.QueryInterface<SharpDX.DXGI.Device>())
                d2dDevice = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Device(d2dFactory, dxgiDevice);

            // Get the Direct2D1 DeviceContext
            var d2dContext = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.DeviceContext(d2dDevice, DeviceContextOptions.None);

            // Create Direct2D1 WindowRenderTarget
            var WindowRenderTarget = new WindowRenderTarget(d2dFactory,
                                                            new RenderTargetProperties
                                                            {
                                                                Type = RenderTargetType.Default
                                                            },
                                                            new HwndRenderTargetProperties
                                                            {
                                                                Hwnd = Form1.Handle,
                                                                PixelSize = new Size2(Form1.Width, Form1.Height),
                                                                PresentOptions = PresentOptions.Immediately
                                                            });

            // Get DXGI.Output
            var output = dxgiAdapter.GetOutput(numOutput);
            var output1 = output.QueryInterface<Output1>();

            // Create RawRectangleF with the Form size
            var FormRectangle = new SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop.RawRectangleF(0, 0, Form1.Width, Form1.Height);

            // Duplicate the output
            var duplicatedOutput = output1.DuplicateOutput(d3dDevice);

            bool captureDone = false;
            for (int i = 0; !captureDone; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    SharpDX.DXGI.Resource screenResource;
                    OutputDuplicateFrameInformation duplicateFrameInformation;

                    // Try to get duplicated frame within given time
                    duplicatedOutput.AcquireNextFrame(10000, out duplicateFrameInformation, out screenResource);

                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        // Create a Direct2D1 Bitmap1 from screenResource
                        var dxgiSurface = screenResource.QueryInterface<Surface>();
                        var d2dBitmap1 = new Bitmap1(d2dContext, dxgiSurface);

                        // Should draw the bitmap on the form, but fails with "WrongResourceDomain" exception
                        WindowRenderTarget.BeginDraw();
                        WindowRenderTarget.DrawBitmap(d2dBitmap1, FormRectangle, 1.0f, BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear);
                        WindowRenderTarget.EndDraw();

                        // Capture done
                        captureDone = true;
                    }

                    screenResource.Dispose();
                    duplicatedOutput.ReleaseFrame();

                }
                catch (SharpDXException e)
                {
                    if (e.ResultCode.Code != SharpDX.DXGI.ResultCode.WaitTimeout.Result.Code)
                    {
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            }

            // TODO: We should cleanp up all allocated COM objects here
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can convert the frame to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` (like in the original sample) and then use `System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage` to draw the bitmap to the Form, but I want to avoid this and draw the frame using SharpDX.
I've tried also to create a `SwapChain` and draw the frame using `Direct2D1.RenderTarget.DrawBitmap` (similar to the [MiniRect sample](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/Direct2D1/MiniRect/Program.cs)) but it fail with the same exception. The same using `Direct2D1.DeviceContext.DrawBitmap`.
I read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/d1121) that this exception means that I am *mixing resources from different resource domains*, but I don't understand exactly what it means in my code. I am not experienced in using DirectX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the `SwapChain` again, instead of the `WindowRenderTarget` and this time I was successful.

- Create a `SwapChainDescription` specifing Width, Height and Handle of your target control (for example a Form or a Panel).
- Create a new `SwapChain` using the `dxgiFactory`, `d3dDevice` and `SwapChainDescription`.
- Get the `back buffer` of the `SwapChain`.
- Get a `DXGI Surface` from the `back buffer`.

(more about creation of `SwapChain`, `back buffer` and `DXGI Surface` in the [MiniRect sample](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/Direct2D1/MiniRect/Program.cs))

- Use the `d2dContext` to create a `Direct2D1.Bitmap1` from the `DXGI Surface`.
- Use the `d2dContext`  to create another `Direct2D1.Bitmap1` from the `screenResource` (as illustrated in the above code).
- Set the first `Direct2D1.Bitmap1` as target of the `d2dContext`.
- Use the `d2dContext` do draw the second `Direct2D1.Bitmap1`.
- Present the `SwapChain`.
- Done.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce your steps but with some doubts, would you mind to share a sample of code doing this ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @forlayo sorry but I don't use SharpDX anymore since it is no longer maintained. Maybe the MiniRect sample can help you.